# Testing warnings in R by comparing strings (best idea?)

Tags: r, warnings

I'm working on an R package and I need some help writing R test functions that are meant to check whether the correct warning is being thrown on C-side code and then caught on the R side. Let me give you some background on what I'm working on exactly:

1. Most of what I'm writing is done on the C side. In addition, I have an if-statement type macro in C that allows the coder to pass a warning to R in the form of a string. The basic premise is that if(statement_true) pass_warning_to_R("Warning string to pass"). What I'd like to do is test whether these warnings are being thrown when I expect/need them to be by writing an R file that uses tryCatch blocks.
2. So far I've written something similar to this:

   ```
   counter <- 0
   tryCatch({

   function_im_testing()

   }, warning = function(war) {
        # Check if warning is as expected and if so increment counter
        if(toString(war)=="The warning I'm expecting/testing for"){
           print(toString(war))
           counter <- counter + 1
        }

   }, error = function(err) {
         print(toString(err))

   }, finally = {
   print("Leaving tryCatch")
   })

   # Stop if the 3 warnings we expected aren't present
   stopifnot(counter == 3)
   ```

This is the method I'm using and, so far, I haven't even been able to get the if statement to execute by trying to get toString(war) and "Warning I'm expecting/testing for" to be the same thing. This, in addition with the fact that this method is pretty sloppy and unreliable, leads me to believe that there's a better way. So, is there a better approach to doing this?

Comment: just print the warning (before that `if`) to see what you should actually expect to see there and that'll help you understand why your match is not working

Comment: It's a somewhat different approach, but have you considered the `testthat` package? It has an `expect_warning` function which can take a string parameter to match the warning against. I imagine other testing suites for R have a similar functionality.

Comment: @eddi I've tried that and literally copied and pasted the output into the second part of the conditional to no avail.

Comment: @BrianDiggs I haven't tried that but I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: @user2263969 - here's an example: `tryCatch({warning("A", call. = FALSE)}, warning = function(war) {print(gettext(war)); if (gettext(war) == "simpleWarning: A\n") {print("got it")}})`. I'm pretty sure there is no way for this method to not work :)

Comment: I hadn't tried using gettext -- will that return a different string than toString?

Comment: Also, thanks to both of you.

Comment: I don't know if that would make a difference for you (it certainly doesn't for my example), I used `gettext` because it was mentioned in the `warning` documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually with warnings you'd like to allow evaluation to continue; `tryCatch` is used to stop evaluation. So instead use `withCallingHandlers` with a handler for warnings that does what you want, and then invokes the 'muffleWarning' restart. The message of an error / warning can be extracted with `conditionMessage`

```
counter <- 0L
withCallingHandlers({
    function_im_testing()
}, warning = function(w) {
    if (conditionMessage(w) == "The warning I'm expecting/testing for")
        counter <<- counter + 1L
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

Since you're writing your own package, it makes sense to create warnings that can be identified in a more robust way, e.g., the following returns a condition that can be used in `warning`, but that has a class 'bad_input' that can be used in `withCallingHandlers`.

```
bad_input <- function(...) {
    w <- simpleWarning(...)
    class(w) <- c("bad_input", class(w))
    w
}
```

To be used like `warning(bad_input("your input is bad"))` and producing output with

```
fun <- function() {
    warning("oops")
    warning(bad_input("your input is bad"))
    "DONE"
}
```

like

```
>     fun()
[1] "DONE"
Warning messages:
1: In fun() : oops
2: your input is bad 
>     counter <- 0L
>     withCallingHandlers(fun(), bad_input = function(w) {
+         counter <<- counter + 1L
+         invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
+     })
[1] "DONE"
Warning message:
In fun() : oops
> counter
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from actually capturing the warning, you need to be aware that warning messages are translated:

```
library(devtools)
with_envvar(c(LANG = "en"), log(-1))
# In log(-1) : NaNs produced
with_envvar(c(LANG = "de"), log(-1))
# In log(-1) : NaNs wurden erzeugt
with_envvar(c(LANG = "fr"), log(-1))
# In log(-1) : production de NaN
with_envvar(c(LANG = "ko"), log(-1))
# In log(-1) : NaN이 생성되었습니다
```

So if you're doing this inside a test, make sure you set the `LANG` environmental variable to ensure that the message doesn't vary according to what computer it's run on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out testthat::expect_warnings()