# Selective suppressWarnings() that filters by regular expression

Tags: r, warnings

In an attempt to generate code that runs without warnings and hence can be run with `options(warn=2)`, I am looking for an implementation of the `suppressWarnings` routine that would only filter warnings that match a given (vector of) regular expressions. Some warnings are just beyond my control, like the famous

```
Unrecognized record type 7, subtype 18 encountered in system file
```

when reading certain SPSS files, and I want to selectively suppress these without affecting possible other warnings.

Is there already an implementation of this functionality?

Comment: How about wrapping your functions in tryCatch? That way you can catch warnings and filter accordingly.

Comment: when I raised this sort of thing on the r development list (I think) I was warned that this approach might fail in a non-English locale, where the text of the warning messages would be different.

Comment: @BenBolker: Good catch. Found your message: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-October/065060.html. I haven't yet followed the entire discussion, but I think that a false negative (=a message that should have been warned about but isn't because it *translates* to an ignored message) is highly unlikely. We can easily cope with false positives: Simply add a regular expression that filters for the translated variant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppress warnings with `withCallingHandlers` and `invokeRestart`, using the "muffleWarning" restart mentioned on `?warning`

```
withCallingHandlers({
    x <- 0
    warning("Unrecognized record 123")
    x <- x + 1
    warning("another warning")
    x + 1
}, warning = function(w) {
    if (startsWith(conditionMessage(w), "Unrecognized record"))
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

This has the output

```
[1] 2
Warning message:
In withCallingHandlers({ : another warning
```

(use `tryCatch` if instead you would like to stop on warning). As @BenBolker mentions this doesn't handle translations; making a more elaborate regex isn't going to be satisfactory. For catching one's own warnings, one could [make and throw a subclass of warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112831/testing-warnings-in-r-by-comparing-strings-best-idea/16113831#16113831).

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a wrapper around @martin-morgan's answer for convenience, it works like `SuppressWarnings` except that you can pass a regular expression to the second argument (which will be passed to `grepl`) or a function that will be applied to the error message, using the dots as additional arguments.

I made it support the formula notation.

See examples below.

```
suppress_warnings <- function(.expr, .f, ...) {
  eval.parent(substitute(
  withCallingHandlers( .expr, warning = function(w) {
    cm <- conditionMessage(w)
    cond <- 
      if(is.character(.f)) grepl(.f, cm) else rlang::as_function(.f)(cm,...)
    if (cond) {
      invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
  })
  ))
}


suppress_warnings({sqrt(-1); warning("ooops", call. = FALSE)}, startsWith, "o")
# Warning message:
# In sqrt(-1) : NaNs produced
suppress_warnings({sqrt(-1); warning("ooops", call. = FALSE)}, ~nchar(.)>10)
# Warning message:
# ooops
suppress_warnings({sqrt(-1); warning("ooops", call. = FALSE)}, "NaN")
# Warning message:
# ooops
```