# How to prevent RMySQL warnings "Unsigned INTEGER in col imported as numeric"?

Tags: r, dplyr, rmysql

When loading data from a MySQL table there are often warnings such as :

```
unrecognized MySQL field type 7 in column 26 imported as character

Unsigned INTEGER in col 3 imported as numeric
```

How can I correctly load the database table into a dataframe so that these warnings are not shown?

I see the function `RMySQL::dbDataType()` can "Determine the SQL Data Type of an S object". Is there a way to tell it which MySQL data type matches which vector type in a data frame?

Comment: The [CRAN page describes RMySQL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html) as a "Legacy 'DBI' interface to 'MySQL' / 'MariaDB' [...] A modern 'MySQL' client based on 'Rcpp' is available from the ['RMariaDB' package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMariaDB/index.html)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not doing anything incorrectly--RMySQL "helpfully" gives you all those warnings just in case that wasn't what you want (it almost always is). @hadley recommends installing the development version (0.11.x) in which this annoyance is reportedly solved. Otherwise, you can use `suppressWarnings(...)`, where `...` is the statement for which you want to hide warnings. Or just live with it till version 0.11 hits CRAN.

Comment: Since I develop a package that is used by others to manipulate data on a server, I prefer to stick with the CRAN version so that the server is easier to maintain. For the moment I have chosen to live with these RMySQL warnings.

Comment: I have to keep Java  at an old version on my machine for a mission critical desktop client, so I've made the same choice. It hurts me because I've basically taught myself to ignore all warnings--it's a bad habit, but it's what I'm stuck with.

Answer (score 2):

Switching from RMySQL to RMariaDB also removes the warnings, see https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/issues/37.

Answer (score 0):

The best option may be `RMariaDB` but if you're stuck with `RMySQL`, you can ignore specific warnings with the function below ([adapted from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182432/3498910))

```
#' Suppress warnings matching regex
#'
#' @param expr Expression to evaluate
#' @param regex Regex pattern passed to grepl
#' @param ... Additional arguments passed to grepl
#'
#' @export
suppress_warnings_matching <- function(expr, pattern, ...) {
  eval.parent(substitute(
    withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) {
      msg <- conditionMessage(w)
      if (grepl(pattern, msg, ...)) {
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
      }
    })
  ))
}
```

I mostly use `dbplyr` to interact with my DBs which means the queries actually get executed when I either `collect` or `print` interactively in the console. If you use `pool`, there is also a warning when calling `tbl` because there is a field lookup in `tbl.Pool` for some reason.

The following should work but isn't perfect.

```
# Override dplyr's collect with a more silent version
collect <- function(...) {
  annoying_mysql_warning <- "Unsigned INTEGER in col [0-9]+ imported as numeric"
  suppress_warnings_matching(dplyr::collect(...), annoying_mysql_warning)
}

# Override base print with a more silent version
print <- function(...) {
  annoying_mysql_warning <- "Unsigned INTEGER in col [0-9]+ imported as numeric"
  suppress_warnings_matching(base::print(...), annoying_mysql_warning)
}
```

It doesn't work when printing in the Rstudio console and I don't especially like overriding generic functions anyway.

A more efficient way to suppress the warning on collection, interactive use / print and sometimes on assignment (when using `pool`) is the following, which works in all my use cases:

```
# Suppress the warning on collect
.S3method("collect", "tbl_sql", function(...) {
  annoying_mysql_warning <- "Unsigned INTEGER in col [0-9]+ imported as numeric"
  suppress_warnings_matching(dbplyr:::collect.tbl_sql(...), annoying_mysql_warning)
})

# Suppress the warning on print (e.g. interactive use)
.S3method("print", "tbl_sql", function(...) {
  annoying_mysql_warning <- "Unsigned INTEGER in col [0-9]+ imported as numeric"
  suppress_warnings_matching(dbplyr:::print.tbl_sql(...), annoying_mysql_warning)
})

# Suppress the warning on `tbl`
.S3method("tbl", "DBIConnection", function(...) {
  annoying_mysql_warning <- "Unsigned INTEGER in col [0-9]+ imported as numeric"
  suppress_warnings_matching(dplyr:::tbl.DBIConnection(...), annoying_mysql_warning)
})

# Suppress the warning on `tbl` for pools
.S3method("tbl", "Pool", function(...) {
  annoying_mysql_warning <- "Unsigned INTEGER in col [0-9]+ imported as numeric"
  suppress_warnings_matching(pool:::tbl.Pool(...), annoying_mysql_warning)
})
})
```

This works great! It's less than ideal because we have to use internal package functions (using the triple colon `:::`), but it's worth it for me!

Avoid using this in prod but, if you do, make sure your `dbplyr` version is frozen to avoid bad surprises.