# Suppress any emission of a particular warning message

Tags: r, warnings

I have a source file (in knitr) containing plots which use a particular font family. I'd like to suppress the warning messages

> In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :   font
>   family not found in Windows font database

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl, label = gear)) + 
  geom_text(family = "helvet")
```

I know I can suppress all warning messages in a script `options(warn = -1)`, and I know how to use `suppressWarnings`. I can also surround a particular chunk in a `tryCatch`.

Is there a way to suppress only the `grid.Call` warning above **throughout** a file?

Comment: I have yet to see this implemented, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Does `options("warning.expression")` provide a clue? I can only use it to remove all warning messages entirely.

Comment: That option is there for replacing warning messages with something more custom made. R's capturing of messages isn't its strong suit (I'm thinking a comparison to Python right now), but is good enough for stats. :)

Comment: Dunno how ugly you want your code to be, but you could redefine the function as the function wrapped in suppressWarnings, conceivably. (I never use warnings or ggplot2, so I might be way off.)

Answer (score 14):

Use

```
withCallingHandlers({
    <your code>
}, warning=function(w) {
    if (<your warning>)
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

For instance,

```
x = 1
withCallingHandlers({
    warning("oops")
    warning("my oops ", x)
    x
}, warning=function(w) {
    if (startsWith(conditionMessage(w), "my oops"))
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

produces output

```
[1] 1
Warning message:
In withCallingHandlers({ : oops
>
```

The limitation is that the conditionMessage may be translated to another language (especially if from a base function) so that the text will not be reliably identified.

See [Selective suppressWarnings() that filters by regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517795/selective-suppresswarnings-that-filters-by-regular-expression/16521046#16521046).