# How can I suppress "Transformation introduced infinite values" warnings in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, warnings

This plot is great. It has everything I need, and the `y=0` value is in a sensible place despite the logarithmic scale. All is great!

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=c(1, 0, 2))
print(ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10())
```

[image]

How can I suppress this warning, and only this warning?

> Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis

Comment: The log of 0 is negative infinity, so the warning is accurate.  Why suppress it?

Comment: @user2554330 every warning is accurate. Why suppress any warning? Because expected, non-actionable warnings (especially in large numbers) may distract you such that you overlook unexpected, actionable warnings.

Comment: You can use `suppressWarnings()` (just wrap your `print()` call in it)

Comment: @duckmayr "`suppressWarnings` evaluates its expression in a context that ignores **all warnings**." That's not what I want. "How can I suppress this warning, **and only this warning**?"

Comment: @bers Very interesting wrinkle! Didn't think about that issue. Not sure, but I'll get back to you if I think of something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress any emission of a particular warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603668/suppress-any-emission-of-a-particular-warning-message) You can find a more friendly version (imo) of the same approach [at this blog](http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2009/05/20/Disable-specific-warnings)

Comment: @duckmayr I had expected a `ggplot2`-based solution, but I agree - in the way my question is asked, this would be a solution.

Comment: If you have zero values, the log-transformation is clearly not appropriate. You should not suppress this warning.

Comment: @Roland thank you for your input. I doubt that you can assess if and why I should have zeros in my data, and whether the log transformation is appropriate or not. But let me tell you: in an exponential dilution series (concentrations 1:1, 1:10, 1:100, ...) with a single negative control that has 0 concentration, the output as shown above is very appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

you can handle it by out of bounds argument. Please find the code below.

```
 library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=c(1, 0, 2))
print(ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10(oob = scales::squish_infinite)
```

Comment: That moves the `y=0` point up, right? Sorry, I do not want that. Also, it still prints the warning.