# Handling multiple warning (ggplot2) warnings with testthat while testing a Markdown script

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, testthat

I have created a markdown script which is producing some `ggplot` graphs. I also wrote a test script to automatically testing the whole markdown by first extracting the code chunks and then executing the script.

With some test data, I get warnings like `Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point)` which I normally ignore and since updating `testthat` to 1.0.0, it is complaining about these warnings because I don't "expect" them.

```
runAllChunks <- function(rmd, envir=globalenv()){
  # as found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753969
  tempR <- tempfile(tmpdir = '.', fileext = ".R")
  on.exit(unlink(tempR))
  knitr::purl(rmd, output=tempR, quiet=TRUE)
  sys.source(tempR, envir=envir)
}

expect_that(f <- runAllChunks('analysis.Rmd'), not(throws_error()))
```

`testthat` is reporting the following:

```
testing analysis script: WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW1.............

Warnings ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. analysis works with "nurias_testdata" folder. (@test_analysis.R#48) - Removed 1164 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
... truncated here ...
```

In older versions of `testthat` I got rid of the warnings by saving the result into `f`. But now testing throws warning messages and also the `not` is deprecated. I changes this to check for `expect_success`, but with the same result.

```
expect_success(f <- runAllChunks('analysis.Rmd'))
```

So not sure how to test my script and take care of the warnings. I wouldn't like to suppress all warnings inside the markdown, also to always filter before plotting is a bit exhausting.

### Update

Thanks to comment ov *bVa* I fixed my `geom_*` sections in the plot to include `na.rm=TRUE` and got rid of the messages.

I am now just wondering, if I expect multiple messages or warning while testing a markdown script, how can I check for those without running the markdown chunks several times? Is there a way of doing this?

I am asking because I have now still a warning message I expect, but I would also would love to check for success with `expect_success`. Or is the way to go by using complicated regex like

```
expect_warning(f <- runAllChunks('analysis.Rmd'), 'warningA|warningB|warningC')
```

Comment: If the warnings are only related to missing data, just add a `na.rm = T` in the arguments of `geom` layers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `na.rm=TRUE`! I changed this and there is now only one expected warning. How can I check for success AND a warning? Or would be `expect_warning` sufficient since it will complain if it is not successful?